# nodejs / expressjs sends empty response on large requestURI

Tags: node.js, express, get

I'm trying to process a GET request with large parameters in express.js.
I'm running node 8 'carbon' in a docker-container with express 4.14.0.

In total the requestURI has 9971 bytes.

e.g. http://somedomain.com/path?param1=dfsgbdg&param2=verrylargeparam

curl response:
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

If I reduce the size under 8k everything is fine.

Is there a hard limit in node or express that could explain this behavior?
Can I increase the limit? (not body, requestURI)
Do I need to switch to POST?

Thanks in advance

c

Here my genreal setup

```
let router = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 10000000000}));

router.use(compression());

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS');
    next();
});


router.get('/my/get/route', myExecFunction);
router.use(another);
router.use(another);
router.use(another);
router.use(another);
router.use(another);
router.use(another);
router.use(another);
router.use(another);
router.use(another);


router.enable('trust proxy');

router.listen(process.env.HTTP_PORT);
logger.info(`Running on http://localhost:${process.env.HTTP_PORT}`);

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Requested headers + URI should not exceed more than 80 kb.
Also, if you were to access this url from browser, there is a limit of 2083 characters that most browser impose; which might be a bottleneck later if you were to add in more params.

Converting it to a post method should be a good option, I think